# R transpose table dynamically for last X weeks

Tags: r

I am new in R. I want to achieve the following.
I have a table as below.

```
rowcounter  ProductNumber   YearNumber  WeekNumber  OrderedQuantity
1   735001E083155   2016    2   10
2   735001E083155   2016    3   20
3   735001E083155   2016    3   10
4   735001E083155   2016    4   60
5   735001E083155   2016    4   50
6   735001E083155   2016    5   20
```

I want to transpose this table so that I can get the last X number of weeks as columns with the proper OrderQuantities for Products. So an example would be;

```
rowcounter  ProductNumber   YearNumber  LastWeek Before2weeks Before3weeks
```

and so on...

the Ordered quantity should come under Lastweek, Before2weeks and so on... 
I am planning to toggle the X something around 6 to 12.

Appreciate your responses on how to make this as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Please show the expected output based on the example showed

Comment: This will create lots of redundant data .. why do you want to do this? (There may be better ways)

Comment: this may help https://www.r-statistics.com/tag/transpose/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely recommend using `dplyr` and `tidyr` in the [`tidyverse`](https://github.com/tidyverse), as it makes restructuring data very nice and natural.

I am not quite sure how you wanted to handle your duplicate records, so I just summed the order quantity.

```
library(readr)                                     
library(dplyr)                                     
library(tidyr)                                     

d <- read_csv('data')      
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   rowcounter = col_integer(),
#>   ProductNumber = col_character(),
#>   YearNumber = col_integer(),
#>   WeekNumber = col_integer(),
#>   OrderedQuantity = col_integer()
#> )

d %>%                                              
## Summarize to remove duplicates                  
group_by(ProductNumber, YearNumber, WeekNumber) %>%
summarize(OrderedQuantity=sum(OrderedQuantity)) %>%
ungroup() %>%                                      

## Create header                                   
mutate(text=if_else(                               
WeekNumber==1                                      
,'Last Week'                                       
,paste0("Before", WeekNumber,"Weeks"))             
) %>%                                              

## Remove unneeded columns
## Use `filter` to remove unneeded rows                            
select(-WeekNumber) %>%                            

## Transpose                                       
spread(text, OrderedQuantity)

#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   ProductNumber YearNumber Before2Weeks Before3Weeks Before4Weeks
#> *         <chr>      <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
#> 1 735001E083155       2016           10           30          110
#> # ... with 1 more variables: Before5Weeks <int>
```